# Issue with Node require in class

Tags: node.js

I'm fairly new to Node, and writing an app with tests, I faced a scenario, where I don't need to load 2 packages for testing (as it will fail to load the packages as they require some binaries, which won't be present in testing environment). I set an environment variable TEST to true to let the app know that it should't load those 2 packages, and the tests run perfectly. However, for production, I get that the package was not loaded.

This is my class code:

```
"use strict";
const config = require('../../config/mainConfigs');

...Other constants...

if (typeof process.env.TEST === 'undefined' || process.env.TEST === null){

    const mssql = require('mssql');
    const oracle = require('oracledb');

    if (process.env.DB_PASS && process.env.DB_PASS != '') var db_pass = process.env.DB_PASS;
    else if (config.Logging.DB.password != '') var db_pass = config.Logging.DB.password;
    else {
        console.error(`There's no database password set. Use either Enviroment Variable "DB_PASS" or set "password" under "Logging" > "DB" in configuration file.`);
        process.exit(1);
    }

}

class db {

    constructor(){
        this._pool = null;
    }

    get_pool(){

        if (process.env.TEST) return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve());

        if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){

            if (!this._pool) {
                this._pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(sqlDbOptions);
            }

            if (!this._pool.connected){
                return this._pool.connect();
            }
            else{
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve(this._pool);
                })
            }

        }else if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'oracle'){

            if (!this._pool || this._pool.connectionsOpen == 0){
                return this._pool = oracle.getConnection(oracleDbOptions);
            }
            else{
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve(this._pool);
                })
            }

        }

    }
... MORE CLASS OPERATIONS...
}

module.exports = db;
```

Then I use the DB in my app like this:

```
const db = require('./db_class');
const db_instance = new db();
```

When starting the app, I call the get_pool() method to establish the connection prior starting the server.

But for some reason, I am getting:

> ReferenceError: mssql is not defined
>       at db.get_pool (C:\Users...\src\db.js:122:34)

If I move the requires outside the if (the one that checks if the env variable is set) it works just fine.

Aren't the requires synchronous?

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: the `mssql` and `oracle` variables aren't in scope.for the `db` class.

Comment: Why if I put them outside that if it does work? How would you solve this?

Comment: `const` is block scoped so they will only be defined within your `if` statement block.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, I didn't know that. Awesome! Changing that to var solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` is block scoped so your two `const` variables defined within the `if` statement block will only be defined and usable within that `if` statement block.

Basically, you can't conditionally assign to a `const` like you're trying to do and have the variable available outside the scope of the block.  So, you have to settle for using a non-const type (`var` or `let`).  I recommend using `let` so you can decide exactly which scope you want it declared in and declaring the variable in that explicit scope.  You can then assign to the previously declared variable within your `if` block.

Here's one usual work-around:

```
let mssql, oracle;
if (typeof process.env.TEST === 'undefined' || process.env.TEST === null){

    mssql = require('mssql');
    oracle = require('oracledb');

    if (process.env.DB_PASS && process.env.DB_PASS != '') var db_pass = process.env.DB_PASS;
    else if (config.Logging.DB.password != '') var db_pass = config.Logging.DB.password;
    else {
        console.error(`There's no database password set. Use either Enviroment Variable "DB_PASS" or set "password" under "Logging" > "DB" in configuration file.`);
        process.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome jfriend00. Thanks for the added explanation!

Comment: @FedeE. - Also, you can change this `if (typeof process.env.TEST === 'undefined' || process.env.TEST === null)` to this `if (!process.env.TEST)`.

Comment: What happens when process.env.TEST == false in that case?

Comment: @FedeE. - It's an environment variable right?  That's a string which isn't a boolean like `false` so it doesn't seem like you need to protect against it being `false`.  If you allow TEST to be an empty string and you want that to count for it being defined, then that might be an issue (but personally I'd just not count it as being in TEST mode if its empty).  In any case, you shouldn't have to test against both `undefined` and `null`.  That's usually a sign of code that isn't as well written as it can be.